# Get first level children of a page ID

Tags: child-pages, children, get-children

I am looking to get immediate children of a page ID.
I tried below code, but it does not seem to work

```
$pageIDchild = get_pages(
    array (
        'parent'  => 0, 
        'child_of' =>$pageID,
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
    )
);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [`get_pages()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/):

> - **'child_of'**
>   *(int)* Page ID to return child and grandchild pages of.
> - **'parent'**
>   *(int)* Page ID to return direct children of. Default -1, or no restriction.

So to get immediate children of a specific page, you would use the `parent` arg and not `child_of`.

```php
$pages = get_pages( array(
    'parent'      => $pageID,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
) );

// Get the ID of the first child page.
$pageIDchild = ( ! empty( $pages ) )
    ? $pages[0]->ID : 0;

// Or to get all the IDs, you can do:
$all_ids = ( ! empty( $pages ) )
    ? wp_list_pluck( $pages, 'ID' ) : array();
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot !